# How to overlay an picture with a given mask

Tags: opencv, overlay, javacv

I want to overlay an image in a given image. I have created a mask with an area, where I can put this picture:

[Image Hosted by ImageShack.us http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/1381/roih.jpg](http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/1381/roih.jpg)

The problem is, that the white area contains a black area, where I can't put objects.

How can I calculate efficiently where the subimage must to put on? I know about some functions like `PointPolygonTest`. But it takes very long.

EDIT:

The overlay image must put somewhere on the white place.
For example at the place from the blue rectangle.

[Image Hosted by ImageShack.us http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/5756/roi2d.jpg](http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/5756/roi2d.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you would like to put an image in a region (as big as the image) that is completely white in the mask.

In this case, in order to get valid regions, I would apply an **erosion** to the mask using a kernel of the same size as the image to be inserted. After erosion, all valid regions will be white.

The image you show however has no 200*200 regions that is entirely white, so I must have misunderstood...

But if you what to calculate the region with the least black in the mask, you could apply a **blur** instead of an erosion and look for the maximal intensity pixel in the blurred mask.

In both case you want to insert the sub-image so that its centre is on the position maximal intensity pixel of the eroded/blurred mask.

Edit:

If you are interested in finding the region that would be the **most distant from any black pixel** to put the sub-image, you can define its centre as the **maximal value of the distance transform** of the mask.

Good luck,

Comment: Hi, sry the image was downsampled, so the size doesn't match. I will test it with the gaussian pyramid. Thank you

Comment: But how can i locate the area (CvPoint) where i can put the image?

Comment: After erosion of the mask (in you case using a 201*201 square kernel), you have different options: 1) You can scan the image for white pixels. 2) Using cv::findContours, you can get all the valid regions and, for instance, calculate there centres. 3) cv::minMaxLoc to get the position of the maximal pixel.